# MySQL REGEXP multiline text

Tags: mysql, regex

I need help to write a MySQL Regexp search pattern

In a table, I have a multiline text column, for example :

**Row 1**

```
4926
1615
3872
248
```

**Row 2**

```
13872;100=HA&ee
```

**Row 3**

```
38726;100=HA&ee
```

**Row 4**

```
3872
```

**Row 5**

```
248
3872;100=VA
4926
1615
```

**Row 6**

```
3872;
248
4926
```

I want to select the values that contains at least one line beginning with "3872" exactly.
In our examples, the correct results would be **row 1, 4, 5 and 6**.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you need the row numbers or the whole value of the row containing 3872?

Answer (score 3):

Use the following `REGEXP` expression:

```
REGEXP '(^|\n)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]'
```

## Demo:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> '4926
    '> 1615
    '> 3872
    '> 248' REGEXP '(^|\n)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]' AS `1`,
    -> '13872;100=HA&ee' REGEXP '(^|\n)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]' AS `2`,
    -> '38726;100=HA&ee' REGEXP '(^|\n)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]' AS `3`,
    -> '3872' REGEXP '(^|\n)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]' AS `4`,
    -> '248
    '> 3872;100=VA
    '> 4926
    '> 1615' REGEXP '(^|\n)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]' AS `5`,
    -> '3872;
    '> 248
    '> 4926' REGEXP '(^|\n)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]' AS `6`,
    -> '100;3872=VA' REGEXP '(^|\n)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]' AS `7`;
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Excellent.But what if I want to match only if 3872 is at the beginning of a line ? For example, this must not match : 100;3872=VA

Comment: Updated the ans to handle the case you mentioned.

Comment: Isn't `[[:<:]]`redundant, since it is preceded by `(^|\n)` which isn't a word character anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Dylan Su answer, here is what I do:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
where value REGEXP '(\r\n|^)[[:<:]]3872[[:>:]]'
```

Perhaps there is a more elegant way.

Thank you all